# Select date from timestamp SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following row in my database:

```
'1', '1', '1', 'Hello world', 'Hello', '2014-01-14 17:33:34'
```

Now i wish to select this row and get only the date from this timestamp:

i have tried the following:

```
SELECT title,   FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,'%Y %D %M') AS MYDATE FROM Team_Note TN WHERE id = 1
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT title,   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%e %b %Y') AS MYDATE FROM Team_Note TN WHERE id = 1
```

However these just return an empty result (or well i get the Hello part but MYDATE is empty)

Comment: what is the column format of the timestamp column?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT title, date(timestamp) AS MYDATE
FROM Team_Note TN
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use DATE function for that:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

```
SELECT title,   
DATE(timestamp) AS MYDATE 
FROM Team_Note TN 
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DATE(r.data_registro) FROM registro_financeiro r WHERE id = 1;
```