# How do I select the date from the timestamp in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I have these 2 records out of several others:

```
2023-02-02 18:25:56.000

2023-02-02 18:49:40.000
```

I want to select only the year, month, and day from them.

I just want to query them, right now I have:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `date` = '2023-02-02';
```

but it doesn't return anything because I need to include the timestamp too. The goal is to select the records with that date just so I can display them..

Comment: Where date >= '2023-02-02' and date < '2023-02-03'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select date from timestamp SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151335/select-date-from-timestamp-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-function/) function to extract the date part of the timestamp:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2023-02-02'
```

Note that if you have an index on `date`, it will likely not be used if you use this approach. However, unless you have millions of rows, it should still perform OK.

The better performing, but more awkward approach is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2023-02-02 00:00:00' AND '2023-02-02 23:59:59'
```

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 they finally support expression indexes, so you can index the result of `DATE(date)` and then if you use the same expression in your query, it uses the index.